# Set element size equal to another on UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to build a simple universal game app using XAML.

I have some `Button`s inside a `Grid`. These buttons have a dynamic size according to the grid size.

I then have another `Grid`, which has a size different than the first, with some elements that need to be the same size as the first buttons. I tried using buttons and other grids, but neither worked.

Here's what I have so far:

First button code.
I am binding it's height and width together because I need this to be a square

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
            x:Name="btnCell_0" Content=""
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
            Margin="15"
            Background="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" 
            Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}" 
            Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Second element code. Need to be the same size as the first button.

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"
          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}"
          Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}"
          CanDrag="True">
    </Grid>
```

As requested, here is the whole code. I stripped most part to make it easier to look at, but the result is the same

```
<Page x:Name="page"
    x:Class="quadradomagico.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:quadradomagico"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >


    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid Margin="0,140,0,0" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="280*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"            
                Width="340" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="0, 20, 0, 20">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                    x:Name="btnCell_0" Content=""
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
                    Margin="15"
                    Background="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Drop="btnCell_0_DragEnter"/>

            </Grid>


            <Grid Tag="1"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"
                  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}"
                  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}"
                  CanDrag="True" DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" Drop="Grid_Drop">

                <TextBlock Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>


        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And here is a screenshot of the app, the blue squares have different sizes

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your whole xaml code here? Cause according to my test, this `Grid` looks exactly the same as the first `Button`.

Comment: Why do you bind the button to itself? If I delete  Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}" , they are the same size

Comment: @JohnZhang because I need it to be a square. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If you want a square, just bind the button's height to it's width, and the grid  below also binds to the button 's width . Don't  bind the button's width to it's height again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested and the code looks well like this :

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"            
            Width="340" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="0, 20, 0, 20">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                x:Name="btnCell_0" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
                Margin="15"
                Background="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"
                Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}"
                >
            </Button>
        </Grid>


        <Grid Tag="1"
              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"
              Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}"
              Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnCell_0, Mode=OneWay}"
              CanDrag="True" >
            <!--DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" Drop="Grid_Drop"-->

            <TextBlock Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI...

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement):

> Although it has an ActualHeightProperty backing field, ActualHeight does not raise property change notifications and it should be thought of as a regular CLR property and not a dependency property.

Same is true for ActualWidth.

The result is generally that the binding will function whenever it is first established (usually during page initialization), but any subsequent size changes to the source element's ActualHeight/Width property will not be replicated to the target element's property.

So for example, rotating a mobile device between landscape and portrait, or resizing the window on a desktop probably won't cause the target element to be updated properly.

Also Visibility of the source element at specific times can cause undesirable and often confusing results.  If the source element is Collapsed when the binding tries to use the source element's ActualHeight/Width property, but subsequently the source element is changed to Visible, the source element will be as expected but the target element may seem to be missing/Collapsed/hidden.  That's because the binding set the target element property to zero from the source element while it was Collapsed, but no changed event occurred on ActualHeight/Width when the source element was subsequently made Visible.

If a property is "read-only", there is a decent chance it won't generate a change notification and thus any binding to it will only function when first applied.

Comment: This is a silly thing Microsoft has done. In practice it is very useful to have the ability to bind and react to any property. Let programmers do what they want to do... It's like they did this to prevent people from going against their style guide.

Comment: At a minimum, a property which does not support change notification shouldn't be bindable.  It makes no sense and only leads developers to assume that binding will work.  In fact I just realized I recently made a change a bound to ActualHeight/Width after having apparently forgotten about all this.  If bindingto ActualHeight/Width wasn't supported, then at least I'd have been advised at compile-time.

Comment: I definitely agree.. Microsoft libraries should prevent us from binding here... But XAML is stupid so...